# Django generic editing views: Styled HTML form is not saved

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm using [Django's generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) `CreateView`, `UpdateView`, etc. together with the auto-generated HTML forms and it works fine:

```py
# views.py
class TagCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'app/tag_form.html'
    model = Tag
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'color']


class TagUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Tag
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'color']
```

```html
<!-- app/tag_form.html -->
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, I want to customize the generated form `{{ form.as_p }}` with bootstrap:

```html
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nameInput" placeholder="Name" value="{{ tag.name }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descrInput">Description</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="descrInput" placeholder="Description" value="{{ tag.description }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="colorInput">Color</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="color" id="colorInput" placeholder="Color" value="{{ tag.color }}">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The page renders nicely exactly how I want it to, but when I click the "Save" button, nothing happens and the data is no longer saved, nor am I forwarded to the detail view like I was before.

I tried following the [Django documentation on how to render fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually); again, it's rendered correctly, but the data isn't saved.

How can I properly customize forms and still use my generic editing views?

**Edit:** My full code his [here](https://github.com/stefanbschneider/ideally/tree/dev/ideally/app).

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation you have to access the form inputs manually and django will populate them accordingly in the template.

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
            {{ form.name }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descrInput">Description</label>
            {{ form.description }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="colorInput">Color</label>
            {{ form.color }}
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

From there, to add classes, you will have to override the CreateView get_form in order to add in what we need:

```
class TagCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'app/tag_form.html'
    model = Tag
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'color']

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(TagCreate, self).get_form(form_class)

        form.fields['name'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Name' })
        form.fields['description'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Description' })
        form.fields['color'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Color' })

        return form
```

Although, this would be a lot cleaner if using ModelForms

Comment: "Although, this would be a lot cleaner if using ModelForms" How would I do that then? Or can I not customize my HTML/CCS when using ModelForms?

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to work. When I click "save" the page just reloads but nothing is saved.

Answer (score 0):

in your form input tag set the "name" attribute, field name as value

something like this:

```
...
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nameInput" placeholder="Name" name="name" value="{{ tag.name }}">
...
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="descrInput" placeholder="Description" name="description" value="{{ tag.description }}">
...
<input class="form-control" type="color" id="colorInput" placeholder="Color" name="color" value="{{ tag.color }}">
...
```

Comment: Just adding `name="name"` etc did not work. The input is still not saved.